# How to save a file from a url with php

Tags: php

How can I save "example.mp4"  from  `$url="http://videos.com/example.mp4"` as "56.mp4" using a variable `$id=56` to `/videos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir('/videos');`

`file_put_contents("/videos/" . ((string) $id) . ".mp4", file_get_contents($url));`

Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php